# Generating random 'su doku' type matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, sudoku

I need to generate some 5x6 matrices in MATLAB. They need to consist of randomly generated integers in the range 1-6, however, an integer cannot occur more than once in a particular row or column.

Here is the script I am currently using to generate random 5x6 matrices:

```
mat=zeros(5,6);

rows=5;
columns=6;
for i=1:rows
  for j=1:columns
      mat(i,j)=round(rand*(high-low)+low);
  end
end
disp(mat)
```

But I don't know how to insert the rule about repeats into this.

I'm sure this is a relatively simple problem but I'm very new to MATLAB and haven't been able to generate something that satisfies these conditions. I'd be greatful for any assistance anyone can give.

Comment: A side point on the code you have posted, if you use round() then you will not get a uniform distribution. Rather use floor() or ceil() otherwise you'll find that the frequency of getting your highest and also your lowest integer is half of what it should be.

Comment: @Dan: good catch! Another correct way of getting random integers is to use MATLAB's builtin `randint()` function. Like `rand()`, it will generate random numbers either singly or an arbitrary-sized matrix at a time.

Comment: @ceving: It's not a homework problem. The numbers 1 to 6 represent possible positions of a food source in an arena for an experiment I'm involved in.

Comment: @Li-aung: My Matlab doesn't have randint(), is it maybe part of a toolbox?

Comment: Actually what I meant was [`randi()` which is part of standard MATLAB.](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html)

Comment: Also @AESmith: In this case it wouldn't help but you could have generated your random grid above without the for loops. just use rand(5,6).

Comment: @Dan: pretty much every MATLAB function is capable of consuming or producing matrices where appropriate. Ain't MATLAB grand? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to fill the matrix with completely random ints all at once. The likelihood of that being a valid puzzle grid is vanishingly low.

Instead, [use the same method as used by Sudoku generators](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=481022) - start with a blank matrix and fill in elements one at a time, as restricted by your rules.

Where you have more than one choice for the entry, pick one of them at random.

You might progress something like this (4x4 example for brevity - allowable numbers 1-4)

```
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

Pick first number by dice roll: 3.

```
3 x x x
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

Pick second number from list of allowable numbers: [1, 2, 4].

```
3 1 x x
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

Pick third number from list of allowable numbers, [1, 4]:

```
3 1 4 x
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

And so on.

If your "list of allowable numbers" at some insertion step is an empty set, then your matrix can't be salvaged and you may need to start again.

Also a 10x10 matrix with 5 unique integers is clearly impossible - insert some logic to test for this trivial error case.

---

Edit: Since it's not homework in the traditional sense, and since it was an interesting problem....

```
function arena = generate_arena(num_rows, num_cols, num_symbols)
    % Generate an "arena" by repeatedly calling generate_arena_try
    % until it succeeds.
    arena = 0;
    number_of_tries = 0;
    while ~(arena)
        arena = generate_arena_try(num_rows, num_cols, num_symbols);
        number_of_tries = number_of_tries + 1;
    end
    sprintf('Generating this matrix took %i tries.', number_of_tries)
end

function arena = generate_arena_try(num_rows, num_cols, num_symbols)
    % Attempts to generate a num_rows by num_cols matrix of random integers
    % from the range 1:num_symbols, with no symbols repeated in each row or
    % column.
    %
    % returns 0 on failure, or the random matrix if it succeeds.

    arena = zeros(num_rows, num_cols);
    symbols = 1:num_symbols;
    for n = 1:num_rows
        for m = 1:num_cols
           current_row = arena(n,:);
           current_col = arena(:,m);
           % find elements in $symbols that are not in the current row or col
           choices = setdiff ( symbols, [current_row current_col'] );
           if isempty(choices)
               arena = 0;
               return;
           end
           % Pick one of the valid choices at random.
           arena(n,m) = choices(randi(length(choices)));
        end
    end
    return;
end
```

Invocation and output are like:

```
>> generate_arena(5,6,6)

ans =

Generating this matrix took 5 tries.


ans =

     2     3     6     4     5     1
     6     1     5     3     4     2
     1     5     4     2     6     3
     4     6     2     1     3     5
     3     4     1     5     2     6
```

Don't say I never gave you nothing. ;)

Comment: @AESmith: No worries. By the way - the way to say "thanks" around here is upvote answers that helped you, and accept the answer that solved your question. (Dan probably wins this time.) :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    m = zeros(5,6);

    for row = 1:5
        flag = 1;
        while(flag)
            flag = 0;
            R = randperm(6);
            for testRow = 1:row
                flag = flag + sum(m(testRow,:) == R);
            end;
            if (~flag)
                m(row,:) = R;
            end;
        end;

    end;

    m
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is somewhat similar to my suggested solution above, except instead of generating one number at a time, you're generating a row at a time. Is that correct? (If so, yours is certainly a much nicer implementation by every metric.)

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right - generate a row of unique numbers and compare this to all the preceding rows.

Comment: I like your use of permute. Very elegant.

Comment: That's great, Dan, thanks. I wasn't aware of the randperm function, very useful.

Comment: Yeah me neither - I learned something too :) If this solves your problem, please mark it as answered.

Also if you're new to Matlab, I suggest you make sure you are comfortable with the line: sum(m(testRow,:) == R). Comparing vectors directly like this is far quicker than using loops in Matlab and will make you code much shorter as well.

Comment: some suggestions:  this can get stuck in an infinite loop if there is no solution for a row given the previous ones.  insert a counter or use a for loop instead of while(true).

Comment: suggestion2: flag = flag || any(m(testRow,:) == R); will be faster and skip evaluation once anything is invalid

Comment: Also see my new answer. Why did none of us think of this before?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way of doing it:

Start off with a known valid solution, say this one:

```
>> A = mod(meshgrid(1:size) - meshgrid(1:size)', size) + 1

A =

     1     2     3     4     5     6
     6     1     2     3     4     5
     5     6     1     2     3     4
     4     5     6     1     2     3
     3     4     5     6     1     2
     2     3     4     5     6     1
```

Then swap rows and columns at random. You can prove that each swap preserves the "no-repeats" property in each row and column.

Say you swap row 1 and row 2. You haven't changed the contents of the rows, so the "no repeats in each row" property remains true. Similarly, you haven't changed the contents of any of the columns - just the *ordering* - so the "no repeats in each column" property also remains true.

Here is what I came up with:

```
function arena = gen_arena_2 (size)
    arena = mod(meshgrid(1:size) - meshgrid(1:size)', size) + 1;
    %repeatedly shuffle rows and columns
    for i = 1:10
        arena = arena(:,randperm(size))'; %shuffle columns and transpose
    end
end
```

Example usage:

```
>> gen_arena_2(6)

ans =

     3     5     4     2     1     6
     6     2     1     5     4     3
     5     1     6     4     3     2
     4     6     5     3     2     1
     1     3     2     6     5     4
     2     4     3     1     6     5
```

I'm not sure this is probably "as random" as the other way - but this way is fast and it doesn't need any logic to detect a failure (because it will (provably) always produce a correct result.)

Comment: This is a nice solution. Might need a tiny tweek to cope with non-square grids? Like maybe create it as a square and then after the shuffling delete the excess rows / columns.

Comment: Yes. You can do this either before or after you do the shuffling. (Personally I think the coolest trick in this code is how the columns are shuffled - using `randperm()` to index into a matrix? Genius!)

Comment: Yeah - that's what randperm is for :) I like the use of transpose to switch between shuffling the columns and the rows. Good solution.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if repeating the shuffling makes the result any more random than just permuting the rows and columns once. `arena = arena(:,randperm(size))` and `arena = arena(randperm(size),:)`, run once, would probably shuffle the matrix as much as it can be shuffled.