# How to generate random matrix without repetition in rows and cols?

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

How to generate random matrix without repetition in rows and cols with specific range

**example (3x3): range 1 to 3**

```
2 1 3
3 2 1
1 3 2
```

**example (4x4): range 1 to 4**

```
4 1 3 2
1 3 2 4
3 2 4 1
2 4 1 3
```

Comment: That is actually like solving a sudoku, I do not think there is a simple way for that.

Comment: if you don't want to focus on computational efficiency, why don'y you do simple for loop?

Comment: ok help me with exemple using a loop :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888531/generating-random-su-doku-type-matrices-in-matlab + http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28168-sudoku-generator

Comment: How *random* does it have to be? :)

Comment: FYI what you are looking for is a Latin Square generator.

Comment: MATLAB file exchange has the [code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12315-latsq) for latin square generator.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar The file exchange implementation seems to be the same as sed's except for creating the circulant matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm will do the trick, assuming you want to contain all elements between `1` and `n`

```
%// Elements to be contained, but no zero allowed
a = [1 2 3 4];
%// all possible permutations and its size
n = numel(a);

%// initialization
output = zeros(1,n);
ii = 1;

while ii <= n;

    %// random permuation of input vector
    b = a(randperm(n));
    %// concatenate with already found values
    temp = [output; b];

    %// check if the row chosen in this iteration already exists
    if ~any( arrayfun(@(x) numel(unique(temp(:,x))) < ii+1, 1:n) )
        %// if not, append
        output = temp;
        %// increase counter
        ii = ii+1;
    end
end

output = output(2:end,:) %// delete first row with zeros
```

It definitely won't be the fastest implementation. I would be curios to see others.
The computation time increases exponentially. But everything up to 7x7 is bearable.

Comment: i'm not lucky i need 11*11 matrix matlab return : Out of memory !!

Comment: yes, perms is a problem. I posted an alternative approach, see if that works better for you.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I provided alternative approach )

Answer (score 4):

A way of approaching this problem is to generate a circular matrix and shuffle it.

```
mat_size = 4    
A = gallery('circul', 1:mat_size);                   % circular matrix
B = A( randperm(length(A)) , randperm(length(A)) );  % shuffle rows and columns with randperm
```

It gives

```
A =
 1     2     3     4
 4     1     2     3
 3     4     1     2
 2     3     4     1

B =
 3     4     1     2
 2     3     4     1
 4     1     2     3
 1     2     3     4
```

This method should be fast. An 11 size problem is computed in 0.047021 seconds.

Comment: Drat, beat me by a hair ;) Although I am glad to learn about the circulant test matrix. I was doing it the hard way.

Comment: Nice, did not think about it ))

Comment: Very neat, I actually already had the circulant matrix, but couldn't manage to shuffle it. Blackout ;)

Comment: I could not prove that all of the possible valid matrices would be produced, much less that they were all equally likely. One extra step I used was to perform a randperm on the initial values. Kind of like a replacement cipher.

Comment: @Cheery That's why I threw in the extra randperm, so that the initial values were randomized before putting them in the circulant matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote another code (interesting to compare timings and, if possible, to make it parallel). Also had problem with `perms` (needed to restart Matlab to be able to generate for 11 elements, I have x64 and 16GB of memory). Than I decided to keep characters instead of the numbers, reducing the memory occupied by the matrix. It, of course, generates all permutations, and I shuffle them in the beginning, selecting in the loop in a new random order. It runs faster this way and 'eats' less memory. Time for 11 x 11 (of course it differs from run to run) is shown in results.

```
clear all;
t = cputime;

sze = 11;
variations = perms(char(1 : sze)); % permutations
varN = length(variations);
variations = variations(randperm(varN)', :); % shuffle
sudoku = zeros(sze, sze);
sudoku(1, :) = variations(1, :); % set the first row
indx = 2;

for ii = 2 : varN
    % take a random index 
    rowVal = variations(ii, :);
    % check that row numbers do not present in table at
    % corresponding columns
    if (~isempty(find(repmat(rowVal, sze, 1) - sudoku == 0, 1)))
        continue;
    end;
    sudoku(indx, :) = rowVal;
    disp(['Found row ' num2str(indx)]);
    indx = indx + 1;
    if indx > sze, break; end;
end;

disp(cputime - t);
disp(sudoku);
```

Result

```
  252.9712 seconds

     7    11     3     9     6     2     4     1     8    10     5
     1     9     6     3    10     7    11     5     2     4     8
     9     6    11     8     2    10     1     7     4     5     3
     4    10     7    11     1     8     5     2     6     3     9
     2     5     9     1     3     6     8     4    10     7    11
    10     3     5     6     7     4     2     9    11     8     1
     6     4     2    10     8     5     3    11     9     1     7
     3     8    10     4    11     1     7     6     5     9     2
    11     1     8     5     4     9     6     3     7     2    10
     5     2     4     7     9     3    10     8     1    11     6
     8     7     1     2     5    11     9    10     3     6     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a memory-efficient approach. The time it takes is random, but not very large. All possible output matrices are equally likely.

This works by randomly filling the matrix until no more positions are available or until the whole matrix has been filled. The code is commented so it should be obvious how it works.

For size 11 this takes of the order of a few thousands or tens of thousands attempts. On my old laptop that means a (random) running time from a few seconds to tens of seconds.

It could perhaps be sped up using `uint8` values instead of `double`. I don't think that brings a large gain, though.

The code:

```
clear all
n = 11; %// matrix size
[ ii jj ] = ndgrid(1:n); %// rows and columns of S
ii = ii(:);
jj = jj(:);
success = 0; %// ...for now
attempt = 0; %// attempt count (not really needed)
while ~success
    attempt = attempt + 1;
    S = NaN(n, n); %// initiallize result. NaN means position not filled yet
    t = 1; %// number t is being placed within S ...
    u = 1; %// ... for the u-th time
    mask = true(1, numel(ii)); %// initiallize mask of available positions
    while any(mask) %// while there are available positions
        available = find(mask); %// find available positions
        r = randi(numel(available), 1); %// pick one available position
        itu = ii(available(r)); %// row of t, u-th time 
        jtu = jj(available(r)); %// col of t, u-th time
        S(itu, jtu) = t; %// store t at that position
        remove = (ii==itu) | (jj==jtu);
        mask(remove) = false; %// update mask of positions available for t
        u = u+1; %// next u
        if u > n %// we are done with number t
            t = t+1; %// let's go with new t
            u = 1; %// initiallize u
            mask = isnan(S(:)); %// initiallize mask for this t
        end
        if t > n %// we are done with all numbers
            success = 1; %// exit outer loop (inner will be exited too)
        end
    end
end
disp(attempt) %// display number of attempts
disp(S) %// show result
```

An example result:

```
10    11     8     9     7     2     3     4     1     6     5
 8     4     2     1    10    11     6     5     7     9     3
 2     3     5     6    11     8     1    10     4     7     9
 9     8     7     4     6    10    11     3     5     1     2
 3     5     9     8     2     1     4     7     6    11    10
11     9     4     5     3     6     2     1     8    10     7
 1     2     6     3     8     7     5     9    10     4    11
 7     1    11    10     5     4     9     8     2     3     6
 4     7     1     2     9     3    10     6    11     5     8
 6    10     3    11     1     5     7     2     9     8     4
 5     6    10     7     4     9     8    11     3     2     1
```